# How to saveAsTable to s3?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

It looks like this will error out

```
df.write()
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .option("compression", "snappy")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .bucketBy(32,"column")
  .sortBy("column")
  .parquet("s3://....");
```

With error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'save' does not support bucketing right now; at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.assertNotBucketed(DataFrameWriter.scala:314)
```

I see `saveAsTable("myfile")` is still supported but it only writes locally. How would I take that `saveAsTable(...)` output and put it on s3 after the job is done?

Comment: Parition by makes a new file per the column, bucket by creates a hash key and evenly distributes across N buckets. They do different things. In my case the column I want to bucket is user ID, which is all unique. What I really want is a sortkey/index, which bucketby provides.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
    You Can use like below:

    df
                .write()
                .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
                .option("compression", "snappy")
                .option("path","s3://....")
                .mode("overwrite")
                .format("parquet")
                .bucketBy(32,"column").sortBy("column")
                .saveAsTable("tableName");
```

This will create a external table pointing to the S3 location
.option("path","s3://....") is the catch here

Comment: Is that table queryable by Athena for example ?

Comment: This can be queried with Athena, if you scan the path with AWS Glue Crawler, or connect the spark to Glue's Metastore as specified [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore)